# MPandroidChart) How to apply two colors to setFillColor

Tags: java, android, canvas, mpandroidchart

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ob2gs.png)

What I've tried.
Please help me..  I really don't know. 
I think it's related to canvas class.

CustomLineChartRenderer

It seems to me that color is not filled according to x value, but color is filled at once.

It's hard because I'm not used to canvas. Please help me.

Here are three methods for drawing lines and filling in colors.

```
   @Override
protected void drawLinearFill(Canvas c, ILineDataSet dataSet, Transformer trans, XBounds bounds) {
    final Path filled = mGenerateFilledPathBuffer;

    final int startingIndex = bounds.min;
    final int endingIndex = bounds.range + bounds.min;
    final int indexInterval = 128;

    int currentStartIndex = 0;
    int currentEndIndex = indexInterval;
    int iterations = 0;

    // Doing this iteratively in order to avoid OutOfMemory errors that can happen on large bounds sets.
    do {

        currentStartIndex = startingIndex + (iterations * indexInterval);
        currentEndIndex = currentStartIndex + indexInterval;
        currentEndIndex = currentEndIndex > endingIndex ? endingIndex : currentEndIndex;

        if (currentStartIndex <= currentEndIndex) {
            generateFilledPath(dataSet, currentStartIndex, currentEndIndex, filled);

            trans.pathValueToPixel(filled);

            final Drawable drawable = dataSet.getFillDrawable();
            if (drawable != null) {

                drawFilledPath(c, filled, drawable);
            } else {
               //////Here part of applying color
                drawFilledPath(c, filled, dataSet.getFillColor(), dataSet.getFillAlpha());
            }
        }

        iterations++;

    } while (currentStartIndex <= currentEndIndex);
}

@Override
protected void drawFilledPath(Canvas c, Path filledPath, int fillColor, int fillAlpha) {

    int color = (fillAlpha << 24) | (fillColor & 0xffffff);

    if (clipPathSupported()) {
        Log.e("clipPathSupported","1");
        int save = c.save();

        c.clipPath(filledPath);

        c.drawColor(color);
        c.restoreToCount(save);
    } else {
        Log.e("clipPathSupported","2");
        // save
        Paint.Style previous = mRenderPaint.getStyle();
        int previousColor = mRenderPaint.getColor();

        // set
        mRenderPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        mRenderPaint.setColor(color);

        c.drawPath(filledPath, mRenderPaint);

        // restore
        mRenderPaint.setColor(previousColor);
        mRenderPaint.setStyle(previous);
    }
}

private void generateFilledPath(final ILineDataSet dataSet, final int startIndex, final int endIndex, final Path outputPath) {


    final float fillMin = dataSet.getFillFormatter().getFillLinePosition(dataSet, mChart);
    final float phaseY = mAnimator.getPhaseY();
    final boolean isDrawSteppedEnabled = dataSet.getMode() == LineDataSet.Mode.STEPPED;

    final Path filled = outputPath;
    filled.reset();

    final Entry entry = dataSet.getEntryForIndex(startIndex);

    filled.moveTo(entry.getX(), fillMin);
    filled.lineTo(entry.getX(), entry.getY() * phaseY);

    // create a new path
    Entry currentEntry = null;
    Entry previousEntry = entry;
    for (int x = startIndex + 1; x <= endIndex; x++) {

        currentEntry = dataSet.getEntryForIndex(x);

        if (isDrawSteppedEnabled) {
            filled.lineTo(currentEntry.getX(), previousEntry.getY() * phaseY);
        }

        filled.lineTo(currentEntry.getX(), currentEntry.getY() * phaseY);

        previousEntry = currentEntry;
    }

    // close up
    if (currentEntry != null) {
        filled.lineTo(currentEntry.getX(), fillMin);
    }

    filled.close();
}
```

Comment: which type of chart you use Line or bar graph

Comment: I'm using a line chart

Comment: please follow this link to resolve your problem
https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/blob/master/MPChartExample/src/main/java/com/xxmassdeveloper/mpchartexample/LineChartActivityColored.java

Answer (score 0):

You can use shader, same :

```
 mRenderPaint.shader = LinearGradient(fromX, fromY, toX, toY, color1,
                            color2,
                            Shader.TileMode.CLAMP)
```

Comment: Thank you for the hint. But as I've applied it, there's a problem where the boundaries of the two colors are not clear.